# Why does the MySQL query fail within this Lua script?

Tags: mysql, lua

So I have a little game that is using LuaJIT and also LuaPower's MySQL client library.

Now, I have successfully made a connection and I am also able to select tables for example, but I was unable to insert any data into the tables.

The error itself is:

> FATAL ERROR [UNHANDLED EXCEPTION]: Attempt to call uninitialized function pointer

Here is my Lua code, so you can understand what I am trying to do:

```lua
addhook("join", "onJoin")
addhook("minute", "saveStats")
addhook("say", "logChat")
addhook("say","onSay")

local mysql = require'mysql'

-- MySQL Connection Details:
sql_host = "localhost" -- Host
sql_user = "root" -- USER
sql_password = "1c%CIuROpD17" --Pass
sql_db_name = "cs2d" -- DBNAME
sql_port = 3306 

local con = mysql.connect(sql_host, sql_user, sql_password, sql_db_name, 'utf8')

function onJoin(id)
local usgn = player(id, "usgn")
local ip = player(id, "ip")
local name = player(id, "name")
local datime = os.date("%c")

     if usgn > 0 then
          -- con:query("INSERT INTO `logins`(`col_int`,`col_varchar`,`col_varchar`,`col_varchar`,`col_datetime`) VALUES (usgn, ip, name, datime)")
          print("a")
          msg("new player joined!")

     elseif usgn == 0 then
         -- con:query("INSERT INTO `logins`(`col_int`,`col_varchar`,`col_varchar`) VALUES (name, datime)")
     end

end
```

Unfortunately the query seems to be incorrect format or at least no real clue on which way could I make this happen.

I can't seems to debug it further. But I believe must be related the way I am trying to make the query, as for example selecting tables works with with the same connection.

Comment: It's not a Lua error, so it's a bug in some C module you're using. "Uninitialized function pointer" sounds like something might have gone wrong when creating a new object, but it might not be something you can fix.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I somehow solved the issue, so that partial function is working already perfectly, but made a new function and again managed to get this fatal error.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Could you please answer this question with your reply? Seems it's the problem actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that you get this error as the result of the SQL query. Since you don't provide a complete example, it's difficult to say what's going on, but I'd start with simplifying the code and figuring out where exactly the error is thrown (for example, you don't check the return value from `mysql.connect` call, which may return `nil`).

Comment: He might be passing nil from lua to something in c land.

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue, but I am starting to think there is an issue with the library itself that I am using

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, but a new problem raised https://pastebin.com/uGPRdCvc within this code. Apperently the syntax is OK, I checked in PhpMyAdmin, also the checkUSGN returns 6943, which also cool, debug 1 also appears, but if I would put debug 2 after the query line, that doesn't appear.

Comment: @Paul Kulchenko, the connection is working, as I have said, I tested that, but the rest didn't work, now it is :) 

However it seems the library is a pain..